# Is it possible to create a transaction in pure python without needing to run bitcoin locally?

Tags: raw-transaction, python

Lets say I have a bitcoin address that has 10 BTC sent to it. I also have the private key for this address

Using Python (2 or 3) is there a way to create a signed transaction (which I believe is a long string of hex digits) that can then be sent to an external service (bockchain.info or whatever) for network propogation.

It seems all the python libraries for making transactions require a connection to the bitcoind rpc interface. In my application, there will be no locally ran bitcoind.

I'm thinking the code I'm looking for is like this:

```
address = '1ALis8zeW1XduXf98ZjoL4EKLen5mVA1q4'
private = '5KiUZd5as1TKsiwnt1KiPgiECtXiuF9BS1MxrAgedNrXcScm4d5'

from some_btc_library import make_transaction

tx_hex = make_transaction(
    inputs=[[address, private]],
    to='123rn4tNGhf1ZehQHLohYn8WRQYhjeGSCw',
    amount=3,
    miner_fee=0.0001
)

send_to_exteral_service(tx_hex)
print "transaction complete"
```

Answer (score 15):

In case you have not seen it, there is a good (IMHO) article which describes how to generate a transaction "manually" using "raw" python (no bitcoin libs or RPC): 
["Bitcoins the hard way: Using the raw Bitcoin protocol"](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html)

Answer (score 9):

[Vitalik Buterin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitalik_Buterin) has recently shared [Pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools), a nice and simple-to-use Python library for handcrafting Bitcoin transactions. [The example](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools#example-usage-best-way-to-learn--) shows the basic workflow, which is pretty much what you have described in your example (just broken down to few more steps).

If you need more help, [this nice article](http://whatdoesthequantsay.com/2014/05/04/bitcoin-transactions-technically-part-2) explains bitcoin transactions technically and shows examples using the **Pybitcointools** library.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [PyCoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) would serve your needs.

[This test case shows how to construct a transaction.](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/master/tests/tx_utils_test.py)

[This test case shows how to use Wallet Import Format with PyCoin.](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/master/tests/key_translation_test.py)

I'd also like to note that this is not a very good idea. Suppose that your input is actually 20 BTC instead of 10. What will happen is that Bitcoin will interpret the extra 10 BTC as a fee to be collected by the miner.

Comment: Note that in addition to the destination address and the private key, the other piece of data you need is the utxo (id and output number from a previous transaction) which is to be spent. Unless you happen to know what is, you'll need a Bitcoin client (or access to a copy of the block chain) to find an appropriate utxo given the private key.